# Typescript how to remove the last parameter of a function type?

Tags: typescript

Assume I have a function type like this:

```js
type Fn = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void
```

And I want to create a new type with the last parameter removed, how can I do that?

```js
type NewFn = RemoveLastParameter<Fn>
```

Expected type for `NewFn`:

```js
type NewFn = (a: number, b: string) => void
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
type Pop<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer U, any] ? U : never

type RemoveLastParameter<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    (...args: Pop<Parameters<T>>) => ReturnType<T>
```

Here `Pop` is a type that gets all members except the last of a tuple as `U` and then returns `U`.

Then `RemoveLastParameter` simply accepts any function type and constructs a new function type with the function `Parameters` `Pop`ped.

Proof:

```
type Fn = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void
type NewFn = RemoveLastParameter<Fn>
// (a: number, b: string) => void


declare const newFn: NewFn
newFn(1, 'abc') // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9mAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZygENsQBtAXQD4oBeKVDLPQsgOg4EtsAzCAJygBVADTFSFKAH5hUAFxRsEAG4CAsAChNoSFABKEALZxVAGSL5gMIvyKGIWfijSYcBKAAoObGwHN8CiTkFACUdDRBNLSaULGe3n4BsAiI1rb2jvgoVFRhtDTKcJy4mtrg0ABi2HSeRArYAK6GAEYCYs0KlvzcvmIAxgrNcHAANhAkeQVFJRo60AByEADuVTUGxmYWVjZ2DgKIVVSaAPTHcVAAelKlWhq4EH0jNtB9cNiWistVCosr2JpKP4eACMYgA5ERmn0wWFTlAlnB+ABrfBAA)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to infer the return type of the initial function too, as I want to apply it to function where it doesn't return void?

I tried to use conditional type and `infer` within generic, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Wait I am able to change it like this and get what I want:

`type RemoveLastParameter<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
(...args: Pop<Parameters<T>>) => ReturnType<T>`

Comment: Yep that's exactly right. I've updated answer as well.